# Change TFS Alert Email Subject Line

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We are running TFS Visual Studio online. Is there a way to configure the email subject line of alert emails to be more user friendly/Readable

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not something you can do with VSOnline. On premise TFS has some templates on the App Server(s) IIRC that you can edit.

I can't see the VSO team adding customisation, but you could always log something on [UserVoice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com) and see what happens.

You could consider using the [Service Hooks](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/explore/explore-vso-vsi) to push notifications to another service that could then create the e-mails. I've not tried this so I don't know how scalable it will be.

Comment: Seems like a simple task. Why can't they make this a feature? lol

Comment: Depends if you want it to be a static title, or a dynamic one. Then you'd need some sort of format string for adding variables. I think there are a couple of templates on prem that you have to edit. No idea if they have the title. You never know, if you log it, they might consider it.